# how to convert string to datetime in c#.net

Tags: c#, datetime, type-conversion, runtime-error

I want to convert "2017-07-31 08:08:24" to datetime in c#.net and I am using windows 10 and I get error

```
Datetime dt=datetime.parse("2017-07-31 08:08:24");


Error "string was not recognized as a valid datetime"
```

and cultureInfo is persian

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact(v=vs.110).aspx)** as follows,

```
 DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("2017-07-31 08:08:24", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Bad questions generate bad answers. Instead of answering it, it would be better to close vote as duplicate in my opinion.